# How to add style on a particular image when hovering in ReactJS?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks

The problem is that I wanted to add a border to the image and display a **Card** that contains information when hovering but instead it displays to all the images.

After fetching data from a movie API, I stored the response in the state:

```
const [movies, setMovies] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    /**side-effects**/
    setMovies(response.data)
 
},[])
```

then

```
let style = {
    display: 'none'
  };
let imgStyle = {};

if(hover){
    style = {
      display: 'block'
    }
    imgStyle = {
      border: 1px solid white
    }
  }
  if(movies.length > 1) {
    display = (
      <div className="MovieContainer">
        <h2>Trending this week</h2>
        <Carousel>
          {movies.map((movie) => {
            return (
              <>
                <img
                  style={imgStyle}
                  onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
                  onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}
                  className="Images"
                  key={movie.id}
                  src={movie.image}
                  alt={movie.title}
                />
                <Card style={style}>{movie.title}</Card>
              </>
            );
          })}
        </Carousel>
      </div>
    );
  }

but instead of adding a style to the *hovered* image, it also adds the style to all images.

I also tried using css for the border and it works the way I wanted but I couldn't think of any way for the Cards to show up when hovering
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you do this modification directly in css file, you can just add to your css

```
img:hover { "2px solid black" }
```

instead of doing inline styling and using `onMouseEnter` `onMouseLeave`

Comment: Yes, I already tried doing it and it works the way I wanted. But, aside from adding borders I also wanted to add a Card when hovering on a certain image. The Card contains some information about the movie....

Comment: Can you share that part of your code becasue it is not in your code and question

Comment: sure, I apologize for not being clear and thank you for taking your time to help me solve this problem

Comment: I see now. What you can do is instead of wrapping your image and card in <> </>, wrap them in a div and add hover effect on div instead of image. For the card component do display:none when there is no hover then do display flex or block when there is hover on div. You can control it like div:hover cardClassName { display:block }. You have to cancel all inline styling of course to see effects